# Are Apache Spark or an SQL server solutions for memory-limited local data manipulation?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, large-data

I have been assigned an 8GB RAM desktop at work which I can't modify. My job involves data manipulation on a group of ~1GB, ~8M row tables.

Certain analyses I need to do would be considerably simpler to implement if I could merge all the files but this means R, which is the tool I currently am using, won't be able to load the merged file at all.

I've asked around and was told that using Apache Spark or setting up a local SQL server would solve the issue and let me ignore memory limitations for data processing steps (the expected output always consists of only a handful of total counts). I'd just like to be sure these will actually work like that before installing anything.

(as a bonus question, I wonder how software like SPSS manages to load and work on huge datasets without a hitch and why R can't implement a similar method)

Comment: Work for what? We have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was thinking of any arbitrary manipulation of the data that will return a small output. For a specific example, counting the number of times each unique item ID shows up.

Comment: What format is your data currently in?

Comment: Lots of .csv files each representing a month of patient visits in an entire country's health system. Some analyses require me to look through years worth of data to identify people with some past condition.

Comment: Then loading this into a database would make the most sense. Or perhaps a nosql solution like mongodb. But being able to query your data is paramount to doing analysis. Pouring through csv files is not recipe for success.

Comment: I suspected as much but I am not terribly tech savy. Thanks for the information.

Comment: .csv data is convenient to load into a SQL database, but it's also natively supported by Spark. You have to specify the csv plugin with something like `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0`. But you can read/write .csv directly in Spark without any complicated import/export steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Spark and SQL Server can absolutely handle and process larger data than fits into RAM.

Installing these tools shouldn't be a big deal. Uninstalling a local Spark installation is just deleting a simple directory.

Spark is intended for use on clusters of computers, but you can use it on a local workstation.

Spark will also read/write data directly in most flat file formats. With SQL Server, you have to load it into SQL Server tables.